# How to deal with ID at PWA offline first app, when it should be generated at server side?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb

I have an app which should work offline. The app is a kind of store. A user creates orders at PWA app, I save that order to Indexeddb with temporary ID, like deviceid_001, deviceid_002...
and add this order id to another table which like a queue for sync.

As soon as I have a connection to the Internet, SW iterates over queue table and sync all orders to a webserver and updates Orders ids in the main table...

The problem, that I have a few pages for making the order... so when I make changes to the order on the first page and it starts syncing (offline ID updated to a real one), the order will be not available at another page.

Sound confusing, but can clarify in the comments.

Someone did anything similar?